# Regex to handle a varying number of variables

Tags: python, regex, str-replace, string-matching

I'm trying to change a string that looks something like this:

```py
s = 'g1 & g2 & (X~(~g1 & ~g2) & ~o1) & (XX~(~g1 & ~g2) & ~o1 & X~o1)'
```

to this:

```py
'g1_0 & g2_0 & (~(~g1_1 & ~g2_1) & ~o1_0) & (~(~g1_2 & ~g2_2) & ~o1_0 & ~o1_1)'
```

So basically I'm appending to each variable _# (underscore and number) as the number of X's in front of it and remove the X's. The problem mostly arises when the X's are before parentheses and that I do not know a-priori how many variables and the logical operators that are in parentheses.

I try to do this in Python. I am going backwards from the most number of X's (Because, if I start looking for g1's, all of them will change). So this is the sequence:

```py
import re
xs = 'X'*n
while n>0:
  # this is for when we have parentheses
  s = re.sub('%s([~]*)([(]+[~]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) ([&|]*) ([~]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)([)]+)'%xs, \
                          r'\1\2_%d \3 \4_%d\5'%(n,n), s)
  # this is for normal variables
  s = re.sub('%s([~]*[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)'%xs, r'\1_%d'%n, s) 
  xs = xs[:-1]
  n -= 1
```

And going down to no X's.
The problem is that I don't want to impose the structure of 'o/g &/| o/g'. and I want it to be variable-length of names and operators, but still assign the correct names. E.g., to handle:

```py
XX(~g1 & ~g2 | ~k3)  --> (~g1_2 & ~g2_2 | ~k3_2)
```

How can I do it with Regex?

Comment: I think this might be too complex for a regex. Consider parsing the string one character at a time, using a state machine approach (the state being the number of X's)

Comment: If there can only be one nested level of parentheses, you can still use a regex, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Duk6SE). It will be  a bit simpler if you can use PyPi regex library.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, your answer works perfectly, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with `re`:

```
import re
def rep_x(d, c = 0):
   s, f = '', 0
   while d:
      if d[0] == ')':
         return s+')', d[1:]
      if d[0] == '(':
         [_s, d], f = rep_x(d[1:], c = c+f), 0
         s += '('+_s
      elif (x:=re.findall('^X+', d)):
         d = d[(f:=len(x[0])):]
      elif (x:=re.findall('^\w+', d)):
         s, f, d = s + x[0]+'_'+str(f+c), 0, d[len(x[0]):]
      else:
         s, d = s+d[0], d[1:]
   return s, d

r1, _ = rep_x('g1 & g2 & (X~(~g1 & ~g2) & ~o1) & (XX~(~g1 & ~g2) & ~o1 & X~o1)') 
r2, _ = rep_x('XX(~g1 & ~g2 | ~k3)')
```

Output:

```
'g1_0 & g2_0 & (~(~g1_1 & ~g2_1) & ~o1_0) & (~(~g1_2 & ~g2_2) & ~o1_0 & ~o1_1)'
'(~g1_2 & ~g2_2 | ~k3_2)'
```

Comment: works perfectly! even better than I expected (can take names that are not just "[a-z][0-9]"). I need to trace it step-by-step with the debugger to fully understand what's going on there. Thank you!